# Python strip() Does Not Strip Part Of File Path Name Correctly

Tags: python, string

I would like to strip a certain portion of the path name using the strip() method but I am seeing a result that I'm unable to explain. An explanation of the behavior that I'm observing as well as a solution would be very helpful here.

```
>>> a = 'C:\dir1\dir2\dir3'
>>> b = 'C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5'
>>> b.strip(a)
'4\\dir5'
```

I was expecting the output of b.strip(a) to be `\dir4\dir5` .
I have tried using raw strings and even escaping all the slashes but I can't seem to explain what's going on here.

Comment: The methods for what you thought `strip` does are coming in [Python 3.9](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/).

Comment: String manipulation isn't a good option for this, though, since you get results like `C:\dir1` being considered a prefix of `C:\dir12`. You should probably use `pathlib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@TimPeters has explained why `strip` is not doing what you want. For your application, this code will do what you want:

```
a = r'C:\dir1\dir2\dir3'
b = r'C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4\dir5'

b = b[len(a):] if b.startswith(a) else b
print(b)
```

Output

```
\dir4\dir5
```

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for the edits. They make more sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> help("".strip)
Help on built-in function strip:

strip(chars=None, /) method of builtins.str instance
    Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing whitespace removed.

    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

The argument is effectively treated not as a string, but as a *set* of characters to be removed.  The leftmost character in `b` that's not in `a` is "4", so that's why 4 was left at the start.  The rightmost character in `b` that's not in `a` is the final "5", so nothing was removed from the right end.